# Spring4d custom BuilderInspector not called

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I have many objects registered in Spring4d container,some as Singleton.When Application shutdown almost Singletons correct call own Destroy,but some no and FastMM reports Memory leaks.
I'm looking for a way,how Log which objects have problem.
I try experienced with Container Extension with this simple example:

```
unit Spring.Container.HCV.Extension;

interface

uses
  Spring.Container.Extensions, Spring.Container.Core, Spring.Container.Builder;

type
  THCVLoggerBuilderInspector = class(TInspectorBase)
  protected
    procedure DoProcessModel(const kernel: IKernel; const model: TComponentModel); override;
  end;

  TFakeBuilderInspector = class(TInspectorBase)
  protected
    procedure DoProcessModel(const kernel: IKernel; const model: TComponentModel);
        override;
  end;

  THCVLoggerExtension = class(TContainerExtension)
  protected
    procedure Initialize; override;
  end;

implementation
uses
  Spring.Container.Common;

procedure THCVLoggerBuilderInspector.DoProcessModel(const kernel: IKernel;
    const model: TComponentModel);
var
  lLT:string;
begin
  if model.ComponentType.IsInstance then
  begin
    case model.LifetimeType of
      TLifetimeType.Unknown:            lLT:='Unknown           ';
      TLifetimeType.Singleton:          lLT:='Singleton         ';
      TLifetimeType.Transient:          lLT:='Transient         ';
      TLifetimeType.PerResolve:         lLT:='PerResolve        ';
      TLifetimeType.SingletonPerThread: lLT:='SingletonPerThread';
      TLifetimeType.Pooled:             lLT:='Pooled            ';
      TLifetimeType.Custom:             lLT:='Custom            ';
    else
    end;
    kernel.Logger.Info('Builder: [%s] %s',[lLT,model.ComponentTypeName]);
  end;
end;

procedure THCVLoggerExtension.Initialize;
begin
  Kernel.Builder.AddInspector(THCVLoggerBuilderInspector.Create);
  Kernel.Builder.AddInspector(TFakeBuilderInspector.Create);
end;

procedure TFakeBuilderInspector.DoProcessModel(const kernel: IKernel; const
    model: TComponentModel);
begin
  kernel.Logger.Info('FakeBuilderInspector');
end;

end.
```

In Registration I have

```
container.AddExtension<THCVLoggerExtension>;
```

Container correct call `THCVLoggerExtension.Initialize` but in my inspectors is never called  `DoProcessModel`.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because you added the extension after you called `Build` on the container? Another reason could be simply not seeing any logging - did you place a breakpoint in the `DoProcessModel` to verify it's not called?

To the actual problem: Memory leaks with singletons are almost always a result of the container not figuring out the correct refcounting of those classes. Pass the correct `TRefCounting` value to `AsSingleton` when registering any classes that are not inherited from `TInterfacedObject`.

Comment: Bingo,I registered Extension after container.Build.Now working and I can continue with experience with Extension,Logging resolving etc.Thank you very much Stefan for your fantastic framework.Do you have any simple list of changes and new features in future version2.0?